# How to solve : SQL Error: ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1

Tags: java, oracle, oracle11g, drop-table

When I'm trying to drop table then I'm getting error

```
SQL Error: ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 2
ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows
00604. 00000 -  "error occurred at recursive SQL level %s"
*Cause:    An error occurred while processing a recursive SQL statement
           (a statement applying to internal dictionary tables).
*Action:   If the situation described in the next error on the stack
           can be corrected, do so; otherwise contact Oracle Support.
```

Comment: did you try `purge dba_recyclebin`? It looks like you're hitting some Oracle bug.

Comment: It seems like I can not run `purge dba_recyclebin`.

Comment: purge recyclebin if you don't have DBA role

Comment: That's what I tried and I mentioned on my post

Comment: When you do not have DBA privs. maybe you should contact your DBAs. Such a command should not fail. You can also try to set tracing on your session to see which recursive query was called from that purge command. There is quite high chance, that you will not be able to fix this without DBA privs.

Comment: What does "show recyclebin" tell you? Did you perhaps try to (re-)drop a BIN$ table name? Which shouldn't be allowed, just trying to think how it could have got to an invalid state... You may need to raise a service request with Oracle.

Comment: You changed the question significantly - are you getting that error dropping a table (and if so a normal table or one that is already in the recyclebin), or when you try to purge?

Comment: I was getting error when I was trying to purge table. Now, when I tried to drop normal table. I got same error. So, I changed the question and made it in simple word.

Comment: But if the drop errors only started after the purge errors, they are probably related. *Did* you try to re-drop a BIN$ table before the issue began? You need to contact Oracle support anyway, I think, or at least your DBA who may be able to fix it or may have to contact support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed following line from error.

```
exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows
```

That means Oracle was expecting one row but It was getting multiple rows. And, only dual table has that characteristic, which returns only one row.

Later I recall, I have done few changes in dual table and when I executed dual table. Then found multiple rows.

So, I truncated `dual` table and inserted only row which `X` value. And, everything working fine.

Comment: You must have been SYS to modify dual, which is a really bad idea ([weird things can and will happen](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1562813956388)), so odd you couldn't see the DBA recyclebin. Modifying anything directly in any built-in schema is dangerous.

Comment: Correct. It can be dangerous if we play with `dual` table. But, right now, I didn't had any choice

Answer (score 1):

One possible explanation is a database trigger that fires for each `DROP TABLE` statement. To find the trigger, query the `_TRIGGERS` dictionary views:

```
select * from all_triggers
where trigger_type in ('AFTER EVENT', 'BEFORE EVENT')
```

disable any suspicious trigger with

```
   alter trigger <trigger_name> disable;
```

and try re-running your `DROP TABLE` statement

Comment: It is totally new user. I just created first object and trying to drop it.

Comment: If it's a trigger, it might have been created in another schema. But I agree with the other comments - you should definitely contact your DBA and - if necessary - Oracle support.

Answer (score 1):

I know the post is old and solved, but maybe someone is facing or will face my situation, so I want to leave the aquired knowledge here, after deal with the error for a week. I was facing the error: "ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1" , but with the internal error: " ORA-06502: error: character string buffer too smal numeric or value", this happened only when I try to logon the database, and using an specific driver, trying to connect from an Visual Studio C# application, the weirdest thing on that moment was that I connect from SQLDeveloper or TOAD and everything worked fine.
Later I discovered that my machine name had this format "guillermo-aX474b5", then I proceed to rename it like this "guillermo" without the "-" and the other stuff, and it worked!! Looks like in some drivers and situations, ORACLE Database does'nt like the "-" in the LogOn connection.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue in the windows.

Solved the issue by changing the regional format to `English(United States)`, maybe the solution bit weird but it worked.

[image]