# ORA-00604 hit in Oracle pl/sql

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am hitting error ORA-00604 when executing a program. This is how the flow currently:

Package **package1** have following sub functions / procedures:

- function **faaa**
- procedure **pbbb** - inside will called procedure **xxx**

while procedure **xxx** called ***package1.faaa***

When I try to execute **package1.pbbb** it hit the ORA-00604.
However, it seems to be alright if I just execute **xxx**.

Do you guys encounter this issue before?

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30478070/how-to-solve-sql-error-ora-00604-error-occurred-at-recursive-sql-level-1

Comment: Hi Kaushik,
Thanks for the answer. However, I think the link that you shared is more on issue occur during drop table. The issue I occur is when I try to execute package1.pbbb, it hit the ORA-00604 (it keep repeating package1.faaa).
However, if I just execute procedure xxx, it seems fine and did not hit ORA-00604. Sorry if I unable to describe it clearly.